# Inversión de valores en Python

Tags: python, bucle-for, tuplas

Tengo la siguiente cuestion sobre un codigo para imprimir los valores de unas tuplas.

Mi objetivo es introducir un numero par (por ejemplo el 6), y que me imprima los numeros por pares en el siguiente orden lógico: 6,1,2,5,4,3. Es decir, el numero mas grande, seguido por el mas pequeño, seguido por el segundo mas pequeño, y después el segundo mas grande, y así sucesivamente.

```
num = int(input("Pon numero: "))
tupla = []
for i in range(num):
  tupla.append((num-i,i+1))
print(tupla)

#Lo que me queda es esto. Que es casi el resultado que busco
for item in tupla:
    print(item[0],item[1])

#Resultado:
6 1
5 2
4 3
3 4
2 5
1 6
```

Lo que no soy capaz (después de haber intentado mil cosas distintas) es conseguir este resultado:

```
6 1
2 5
4 3
4 3
2 5
6 1
```

Esto lo he hecho poniengo como ejemplo el numero 6, pero si introdujera por ejemplo el 8, el resultado debería ser: 8,1,2,7,6,3,4,5

¿Que formula podría emplear para conseguirlo?

Comment: Buen día, mencionas en el párrafo que deseas obtener los siguientes números en tuplas de 2 ` 6,1,2,5,4,3.` en el resultado que muestras al final ¿De dónde salen las últimas 2 tuplas?

Comment: Buenos días @HeytalePazguato, las ultimas tuplas salen del mismo resultado obtenido hasta ahora, lo que las he invertido en orden, que sería el objetivo del código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Primero podemos generar una lista con todos los valores del 1 al número ingresado por el usuario

```
nums = list(range(1,int(input('Pon un número:'))+1))
```

Con un ciclo `while` podríamos iterar en la lista anterior buscando la combinación de números mayor y menor de la lista y luego removiendo esos números. Iteramos hasta que la lista esté vacía y agregamos el mayor y menor a una nueva lista que nos servirá para imprimir los resultados.

```
while len(nums) > 0:
    # Buscamos el valor máximo y mínimo
    m = max(nums)
    n = min(nums)
    
    # Removemos el máximo y mínimo de la lista
    nums.remove(m)
    nums.remove(n)
    
    # Agregamos el máximo y mínimo como tupla en la lista
    lista.append((str(m), str(n)))
```

Con una comprensión de listas podemos invertir las tuplas que están en posición impar

```
lista = [e if i%2 == 0 else e[::-1] for i,e in enumerate(lista)]
```

Ya con las tuplas en el formato que mostraste en tu pregunta podemos "duplicar" la lista pero invirtiendo el orden de los índices de las tuplas, es decir, si los índices de la lista original (Tomando como ejemplo que el usuario ingresó 6) son 0, 1 y 2, entonces necestaríamos que la lista final tuviera las tuplas 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0

```
lista = lista + lista[::-1]
```

Y luego con `join()` podemos dar formato a las tuplas para imprimirlas

```
print(*[' '.join(e) for e in lista], sep='\n')
```

Ejemplo completo:

```
# Creamos una lista de 1 al número que ingresa el usuario
nums = list(range(1,int(input('Pon un número:'))+1))

# Creamos una lista vacía
lista = []

while len(nums) > 0:
    # Buscamos el valor máximo y mínimo
    m = max(nums)
    n = min(nums)
    
    # Removemos el máximo y mínimo de la lista
    nums.remove(m)
    nums.remove(n)
    
    # Agregamos el máximo y mínimo como tupla en la lista
    lista.append((str(m), str(n)))

# Con una comprensión de listas invertimos las tuplas en los índices impar (1,3,5,...)
lista = [e if i%2 == 0 else e[::-1] for i,e in enumerate(lista)]

# Agregamos la misma lista pero con orden invertido
lista = lista + lista[::-1]

# Imprimimos las tuplas
print(*[' '.join(e) for e in lista], sep='\n')
```

Muestra del funcionamiento:

```
# Ejemplo 1
Pon un número: 8
8 1
2 7
6 3
4 5
4 5
6 3
2 7
8 1

# Ejemplo 2
Pon un número: 6
6 1
2 5
4 3
4 3
2 5
6 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Una solución:

```
num = int(input("Pon numero: "))
for i in range(0, num, 2):
    print(num - i,  i + 1)
    print(i + 2, num - i - 1)
```

#### Demo

```
Pon numero: 6
6 1
2 5
4 3
4 3
2 5
6 1

Process finished with exit code 0
```